# react-native: unable to invoke navigator within facebook LoginManager function

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk, react-navigation

I am new to react native and i'm trying to invoke the navigator after I have received user credentials via the facebook graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

So I have my first class which sets up the navigator and renderScene.

```
class CupofDoom extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialRoute={{ name: 'main' }}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
     if(route.name == 'main') {
       return <Main navigator={navigator}  />
     }
     if(route.name == 'stats') {
       return <Stats navigator={navigator} />
     }
  }
}
```

The code above will automatically invoke the class Main. This class 'as seen below' contains a custom facebook login button which invokes the method 'handleFaceBookLogin()' when clicked. So everything works fine until I try and run this.props.navigator.push({ name: 'stats',}) it returns, cannot read property 'navigator'.  Note this works fine if I move the navigator prop outside of the Facebook Manager login.

```
class Main extends Component {


  handleFacebookLogin(routeName) {


      LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log('Login cancelled');
        } 

        else {
          console.log('Login success with permissions: '
            +result.grantedPermissions.toString());


          const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {

                if (error) {
                  console.log(error)
                  console.log('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                } 

                else {
                  test = result; 

                  console.log(test.email);

                  this.props.navigator.push({
                    name: 'stats', // Matches route.name
                  })           

                }
          }//response


          const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
            '/me',
            {
              parameters: {
                fields: {
                  string: 'picture,email,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name'
                }
              }
            },
            responseInfoCallback
          );

          // Start the graph request.
          new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
      }//else

      },//function result

        function(error) {
          console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
        }//functionError
      );//loginManager 


  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Grid>
        <Row size={2} style={styles.row1}>
          <View style={styles.titleHolder}>
              <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                Cup of Doom <Icon active name='ios-cog' style={{color: '#ffffff'}}/>
              </Text>
          </View>
        </Row>
        <Row size={1} style={styles.row2}>
          <View>
            <Icon active name='ios-beer' style={{color: '#333333', fontSize: 100, textShadowColor: '#333333', textShadowOffset: {width: 1, height: 1}}}/>
          </View>
        </Row>
        <Row size={1} style={styles.row3}>
          <View style={styles.fbbutton}>
            <Button bordered light block onPress={this.handleFacebookLogin.bind(this, "stats")}>
              <Icon name="logo-facebook" />
              <Text style={styles.text}>Login with Facebook</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

I've also included the Stats class for reference.

```
class Stats extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>{email}</Text>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.props.navigator.pop()}}>
          <Text>BACK</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Again I would really appreciate any advice / help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I actually managed to solve my own question.

So I have my on press action which binds this eg

```
onPress={this.handleFacebookLogin.bind(this, 'test' )}
```

Within my function I declare a global variable and assign it to 'this', which will then enable me to invoke the props.navigator.

handleFacebookLogin(routeName) {

```
  var that = this;

  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      console.log('Login cancelled');
    } 

    else {
      console.log('Login success with permissions: '
        +result.grantedPermissions.toString());


      const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {

            if (error) {
              console.log(error)
              console.log('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
            } 

            else {
              test = result; 

              console.log(test.email);

              that.props.navigator.push({name: 'stats'})  

            }
      }//response


      const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        {
          parameters: {
            fields: {
              string: 'picture,email,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name'
            }
          }
        },
        responseInfoCallback
      );

      // Start the graph request.
      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
  }//else

  },//function result

    function(error) {
      console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
    }//functionError
  )//loginManager
```

}